# How to use actual working timeouts in HttpClient.* methods in C#

Tags: c#, http, timeout

I'm having the issue that setting a timeout in HttpClient in C# a) interrupts a running download if it is set too low, and b) doesn't trigger in some situations. I am trying to find a workaround, and need some help.

I have a pretty straightforward implementation of a HttpClient client call. The problem is easiest to see when downloading a large file. The code looks like this, and I believe this is the correct usage:

```
HttpClient client= new HttpClient()
client.Timeout= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

HttpMessageRequestMessage msg= new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "<URL>");
HttpResponseMessage response= await client.SendAsync(msg, HttpCompleteOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

await response.Content.ReadAsSytreamAsync().Result.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
```

Now this works in principle, BUT:

1. The timeout of 1 minute seems to be an "execution time timeout", that is, it kills the copy even if the file has not been downloaded completely, but is downloading quite well up to that point.
2. If I actually unplug a network cable during the transfer (to simulate a catastrophic failure), the timeout does not fire. I assume that some .Read() method within CopyToAsync simply blocks in that case.

Regarding 1: AFAIK the client.Timeout gets converted to CancellationTokens internally (which is why a TaskCanceledException is thrown), that is, it a) only works if the underlying operation actually checks for a cancellation and b) the underlying operation seemingly doesn't reset the timer on a successful read, since the whole point seems to cancel after a set timeout.

Regarding 2: In many cases, i.e. if the server isn't there at all, or if I kill the server, i.e. if there is a "definite network failure" which the client can recognize, I **do** get a proper exception from this code; but I don't get one in, let's say, more 'problematic network failures' (as simulated by unplugging the network cable from a (wired) server, while the (wireless) client still tries to download.

Now, this is easiest to test on CopyToAsync for a large file, but I have no reason to believe that this works any different on a standard GetAsync or PostAsync, which means that with unlucky timing, those methods might hang indefinitely as well.

What I would **expect** the Timeout in HttpClient to do is a) only count from the last successful read/write operation (which it seemingly doesn't, it counts from the start of the operation), and b) fire in all cases, even if the network goes down (which it doesn't either).

So - what can I do about this? Should I just use another implementation (which?), or should I implement my own timeouts by using a secondary thread which just kills the underlying client/socket/stream?

Thanks.